# Unexpected behavior of Object.assign() in Immer in Redux

Tags: javascript, object, redux

I'm using redux-starter-kit (which includes Immer library for mutable updates) and for some reason this reducer doesn't work:

```
reInitializeState(state, action) {
        state = Object.assign({}, initialState);
        state.someProperty = true; // this does not get set
    },
```

But this one does:

```
reInitializeState(state, action) {
        Object.assign(state, initialState);
        state.someProperty = true; // this does
    },
```

I would expect them to do the same thing. What is going on here?

Comment: They both do exactly the same thing.  This is the premise with React that causes the insistence on using `setState()` - state is supposed to be immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Immer you mutate objects in-place for creating the next immutable copy. In the first example, because `state` comes in as a param, doing:

```
state = Object.assign({}, initialState);
```

reassigns `state` to a new object, so setting `someProperty` on that new object doesn't cause any changes -- you have to mutate on the param itself.

In the second example, you don't reassign `state` to something else, so calling `state.someProperty` and modifying it modifies the original state object.

Answer (score 3):

Reassigning a variable, by itself, will almost never have any effect elsewhere. If you pass a variable as a parameter, then reassign that variable, and the function ends, nothing outside of the function will see any change. Similarly:

```js
let someVar = 'foo';
function reassign(str) {
  str = 'bar';
}
reassign(someVar);
console.log(someVar);
```

Reassigning inside the function above doesn't do anything, because the reassignment does not change what the outer binding of `someVar` points to.

Your second snippet:

```
reInitializeState(state, action) {
    Object.assign(state, initialState);
    state.someProperty = true; // this does
},
```

Here, you're mutating the original `state` object that was passed as a parameter, so the change is seen outside the function. In the other snippet, you're mutating an *entirely new object*, an object which cannot be seen elsewhere in the script, and proceeds to get garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here:

```
state = Object.assign({}, initialState);
```

Is copying `initialState` into a new object, and discarding the contents of `state`. You should be assigning to `state` not to `{}`, and assigning the result to `state`.

```
state = Object.assign(state, initialState);
```